# PCA sklearn ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[1, 3]'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this

```
1   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   4   0   0   ... 0   5   0   0   3   0   0   [1, 3]  0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   ... 6   6   0   [2, 4]  0   2   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   6   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   4   0   0   5   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   [2, 7]  0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I'm trying to use PCA to reduce the dimensionality of my data, but there are some points in the data that are more than 1 dimension like this `[2, 7]`
so when I run PCA I get this error

```
data = pca.fit_transform(z)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[1, 3]'
```

How do I handle this

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla PCA doesn't work when observations have varying lengths.
If `[1,3]` means there were two data points for that individual cell, use a summarization function (e.g. mean or median) to establish a single value for that cell first, then run PCA.

(Also, it seems your `dtype` for those fields is `str` - remember to convert to a numeric type.)

Comment: what about encoding them I tried label encoder and It did convert them, but it give all those lists one label how do I change that

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like you're still figuring out your actual question.  Label encoding is really a separate topic from what you asked here, which is about why you're getting a `ValueError` with PCA.  Consider opening up a separate question for the `LabelEncoder` thread, and describe the problem more completely there.

Comment: I wanted to label them as a solution for this problem, I added a new question please check it and help me if you could 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881360/how-to-handle-mixed-type-data-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: PCA is a reduction that maps your feature space in the most varied row space(~direction), indeed, if one of your datapoint has a irregular input, this would corrupt the computation. Depending on the physical meaning of your list, you should consider taking a mean, geomean, beheading(put to 0), convert to `abs(max())` or something that represent the data well enough.