# How to handle mixed type data in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
1   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   4   0   0   ... 0   5   0   0   3   0   0   [1, 3]  0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   ... 6   6   0   [2, 4]  0   2   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   6   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   4   0   0   5   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   [2, 7]  0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

There are multi dimensional point like this [1, 3]

when I try to do any process on the data Like PCA I get the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[1, 3]'
```

I tried using Labelencoder but I get this error also

```
ValueError: bad input shape (5, 143)
```

How do I handle this? 
given that I want my model to be able to read the data in the list

Comment: So you mean each list like [1,3] needs to be encoded? You may've to write your own label encoder then, checking for types of elements in the list and building a dictionary. Curious what kind of learning you want to accomplish with such list.

Comment: each number represents a week day so this list means multiple days in the same week, so at the end my model should predict the day which will appear in the next week

Comment: I don't it it's possible to read this point as a vector or not

Comment: And you don't want to do one-hot encoding? What's your dataframe shape?

Comment: this is my data frame shape (300000, 143)

Comment: This is not a good way to handle variable length features. You should one-hot encode all the days of the week and then fill 1 in whichever day was present. You can have multiple 1s in a sample representing multiple days in same week. For that you can use MultilabelBinarizer.

Comment: The real answer is here is "don't". Rethink how you can design your model/data without this restriction.

Comment: what if I multiply each element in the list by 10 and summed them, does it seem like a good idea and how do you think it could affect the model

Comment: What happens when instead of 2 days, there are 3 or more days present. Your strategy of multiplying with 10 is not good.

Comment: I see, what about the mean of each list or if you have any suggestions I could try